# RF sampling ADCs(ADC12DJ3200 ),PLLS and regulators placement and layout

Tags: rf, pcb-design, adc, layout, pll

I am novice in PCB component placement and layout. I have just started my career in Hardware design.

We have designed a schematic for Data Acquisition System.

In our design, we are using three RF sampling ADCs ([ADC12DJ3200](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc12dj3200.pdf)) from TI.

ADC12DJ3200 is a Dual Channel ADC. Sampling rate for this ADC can go upto 6.4GSPS in single channel mode.

Maximum supported sampling clock is 3.2GHz.

ADC12DJ3200 supports [JESD204B standard](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slap161/slap161.pdf). One ADC has 16 differential lanes ,so for our design there will be total 48 differential lanes.

Data rate for one lane can go upto 12.8Gbps however as the no. of lane increases, data rate will decrease per lane.

According to JESD204B, two clocks are required for each ADC. One is DEVICE clock and other is SYSREF.

For generating and distributing necessary clocks, we are using two PLL ICs from TI , [LMK04828](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmk04828.pdf) and [LMX2582](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmx2582.pdf) and one buffer IC from Analog Devices [HMC987](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc987.pdf).

Clocking block diagram and flow is shown below:
[image]

ADC12DJ3200 required two different voltages for its operation: 1.9v and 1.1v.

For powering all these PLL ICs and ADCs we are using total 11 Nos. of regulators out of which three are switching regulators and remaining 8 Nos. are LDOs. We are using separate LDOs for each ADC12DJ3200.

Our planned board dimensions are 190mm*186mm right now.

We are planning to use Megtron 6 material for our PCB.

Below is the image of our board right now:
[image]

Position of SMA connectors is not fixed. If we get some useful suggestions for placement of SMA connectors used for ADCs and other signals, we will change the position of SMA connectors.

We need to keep the FMC+ connector on the top right side of the board because of our design requirements.

Now for placement of all the componets on board, we tried to take reference from [TI Eval Board](http://www.ti.com/tool/ADC12DJ3200EVM#1) for ADC12DJ3200.

But TI Eval Board uses only one ADC(we are using three in our design) and also they have placed the FMC+ connector in the middle of the PCB.
 So they have used left side of FMC+ connector for power and right side for Clocking and all the 16 differential output signals from ADC is routed through the middle section of the PCB and no component is placed above the area through which traces are running from ADC to FMC+ connector.

TI Eval Board’s divided sections are shown below:
[image]

Now, as in our board the FMC+ connector is on the top left of PCB and also we have 48 differential output pairs for three ADCs,  which right now we are planning to route through left side of the PCB from three ADCs to FMC+ connector.

And if we also don’t use the area below which high speed JESD outputs of ADCs are running from ADCs to FMC+ connector, we need to use the right side of our board for placing both the clocking section and power section.

***Can we place both power and clocking on the same side of PCB without interference?***

***It will be of great help if someone can guide us where to place the clocking components(LMK,LMX and HMC), three ADCs, switching regulators and LDOs.***

Also if all the power and clocking ICs, cannot be placed on the right side of PCB due to lack of space availability ,can we place some components on the area below which high speed differential outputs of ADCs are running from ADCs to FMC+ connector?

Also as these ADCs are direct RF sampling ADCs, we will be testing these ADCs for input signal upto 10GHz.

**Right now the spacing between one Channel of ADC to other channel is 20mm.
Is this enough for our application to keep the cross talk minimum from one channel to other channel.**

If it seems like more information is required for this, then please let me know.

I have read here only (EE.SE) that if placement is done right, then more than half of the layout is done.

So, please guide us so that we can make our design successful.

Edit 1: We are planning to use signle ground for all the components.That is right now we will not divide the ground planes in AGND,PGND or DGND. If someone can guide us for grounding scheme(like whether single ground plane is ok or dividing the ground in AGND,PGND or DGND required) also it will be most welcome.

Comment: Since 1 Amp switching in 10 nanoseconds,, located 1 cm away from 1 cm by 1cm loop, induces 2e-7 * (0.01*0.01/0.01) * 1e+8 = 2e-7 * 0.01 * 1e+8 = 2e-1 = 0.2 volts into your circuit (ignoring any magnetic field attenuation of the PCBplanes), or 200,000 microVolts, the answer is no. IMHO slower edges will exponentially become worse, because the PCB skin effect will be much less beneficial to you, in any Hfield shielding.

Comment: hi guys... Did I miss any important info which need to be shared for answering this question or guiding me in right direction